# Error to create postgis extension

Tags: postgis, postgresql, installation

when creating the postgis extension

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

I have the next problem

> ERROR: Could not access the file «$libdir/postgis-2.2»: No such file
>   or directory

I use Ubuntu 14.04.5 and PostgreSQL 9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is solved using the command

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.2
```

Comment: should mark your answer as approved