# Migrating an old PG9.5-2.2 database - ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.2": No such file or directory

Tags: postgis, postgresql, upgrade

I put my hands on an old [PostgreSQL](https://postgresql.org/)/[PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) sever (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) where:

```sql
 SELECT version();
                 version                                                                
---------------------------------------------
PostgreSQL 9.5.25 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.5.25-4.pgdg22.04+1),
  compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0, 64-bit
(1 row)

SELECT postgis_version();
ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.2": No such file or directory
```

(Notice that [pgdg repository](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) is enabled)

I want to dump a database on this server to restore it on, at least, a PostgreSQL v.12 installation.

But when I try to use `pg_dump` from PG12, it also says:

```sql
pg_dump: error: query failed:
  ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.2": No such file or directory
(...)
```

So I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208694/error-to-create-postgis-extension) thread and I looked at what is proposed by `apt`:

```sh
$ sudo apt-cache search postgresql | grep -- -postgis

postgresql-14-postgis-3 - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 14
postgresql-14-postgis-3-scripts - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 14 -- SQL scripts
postgresql-10-postgis-3 - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 10
postgresql-10-postgis-3-dbgsym - debug symbols for postgresql-10-postgis-3
postgresql-10-postgis-3-scripts - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 10 -- SQL scripts
postgresql-11-postgis-3 - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 11
postgresql-11-postgis-3-dbgsym - debug symbols for postgresql-11-postgis-3
postgresql-11-postgis-3-scripts - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 11 -- SQL scripts
postgresql-12-postgis-3 - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 12
postgresql-12-postgis-3-dbgsym - debug symbols for postgresql-12-postgis-3
postgresql-12-postgis-3-scripts - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 12 -- SQL scripts
postgresql-13-postgis-3 - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 13
postgresql-13-postgis-3-dbgsym - debug symbols for postgresql-13-postgis-3
postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 13 -- SQL scripts
postgresql-14-postgis-3-dbgsym - debug symbols for postgresql-14-postgis-3
postgresql-15-postgis-3 - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 15
postgresql-15-postgis-3-dbgsym - debug symbols for postgresql-15-postgis-3
postgresql-15-postgis-3-scripts - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 15 -- SQL scripts
postgresql-9.6-postgis-3-scripts - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 9.6 -- SQL scripts
postgresql-postgis - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- Metapackage
postgresql-postgis-scripts - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- SQL scripts metapackage
```

There is no such `postgresql-9.5-postgis` and the only package which doesn't hold a version tag is `postgresql-postgis` but it's apparently based on PostGIS 3.3:

```sh
$ sudo apt-cache policy postgresql-postgis

postgresql-postgis:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.3.2+dfsg-1.pgdg22.04+1
  Version table:
     3.3.2+dfsg-1.pgdg22.04+1 500
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg/main amd64 Package
```

And you will see it's actually a PG15 related package if you try to install it.

I also tried what's on [this](https://postgis.net/2022/01/14/tip-upgrading-raster-from-2-3/) PostGIS web page:

but no luck twice:

```sql
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade();
ERROR:  function postgis_extensions_upgrade() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The PostGIS extension is actually installed:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  extension "postgis" already exists
```

and:

```sql
SELECT extname FROM pg_extension;
     extname      
------------------
 plpgsql
 postgis
 postgis_topology
(6 rows)
```

More tricky, I also tried to symlink the `postgis.control` file of PG12 to PG9.5:

```sh
sudo ln -s /usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis.control  /usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/postgis.control
```

But then this message shows up:

```sql
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no update path from version "2.2.1" to version "3.3.2"
```

So, what should I do the properly migrate my good old PostGIS database to a newer version?

I also tested with the lowest postgis version (postgis:9.5-2.5) available on https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis. The exact same error occurs.

Other things I've read and tried:

- https://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/268-Using-pg_upgrade-to-upgrade-PostGIS-without-installing-an-older-version-of-PostGIS.html
- https://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/278-Using-pg_upgrade-to-upgrade-PostgreSQL-9.6-PostGIS-2.4-to-PostgreSQL-15-3.3-on-Yum.html

Comment: Upgrade compatibility is often limited to only a few releases. Have you tried 9.5->9.6->12 or 9.5->10->12? Worst case would be 9.5->9.6->10->11->12, but then you can also do intervening PostGIS upgrades, too.